# Creating a mutable collection from an immutable one

Tags: java, guava

Let's say I have the following `Map` which is created using Guava's library: (`List<Integer>` is also immutable)

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = ImmutableMap.builder()...
```

I pass this map to a class where I want to create a mutable copy of it and modify it. It is of course possible to do it manually, but is there a way to convert a nested immutable collection back to a mutable one?

Comment: Most JDK `Map` implementations have a constructor that accepts a `Map` and copies in all its elements.

Comment: In this case, List<Integer> is also immutable, so I will get errors when I want to do: `map.get("a").add(1);`

Comment: Oh, the `List` elements themselves are immutable too?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. Actually I use `ImmutableMap.copyOf` to build the immutlabe copy in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, you use Guava and you don't use a `Multimap`? Given your base map that's rather strange

Comment: @fge You are right, it's an old code base that implemented immutability using defensive nested copying. Making the map immutable worked, but in some places I need to turn them back to mutable again, but couldn't find how to do it with guava.

Comment: Well, that's simple, really; `Multimap` implementations have plenty of "copy constructors". For instance, `ArrayListMultimap.create(Multimap)`

Comment: Are you asking about the exact form of the `Map` in the question, or are you looking for a more general solution that will work for arbitrarily complex patterns of arbitrary depth (e.g. `Set<Map<List, Queue<String>>>`)?

Comment: @pbabcdefp I'm looking for a rather more generic solution. I have collections with at most three levels of nesting. That's another reason why MultiMap may not work.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, I'd use an `ImmutableListMultimap<String, Integer>` instead of a `ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableList<Integer>>`.

Then if you want a mutable copy, you can just pass the immutable multimap to the `create` static factory method on one of the mutable `ListMultimap` implementations (`ArrayListMultimap` or `LinkedListMultimap`).

Comment: I have also maps like `Map<String, List<Set<Integer>>>` in which case I believe multimap won't be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. There'e quite a lot of code required to set it up, but once it's done it's really easy to use.

```
public class Main {

    // UnaryOperator and identity are in Java 8. 
    // I include them here in case you are using an earlier version.
    static interface UnaryOperator<T> {
        T apply(T t);
    }

    static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity() {
        return new UnaryOperator<T>() {
            @Override
            public T apply(T t) {
                return t;
            }
        };
    }

    // This unary operator turns any List into an ArrayList.
    static <E> UnaryOperator<List<E>> arrayList(final UnaryOperator<E> op) {
        return new UnaryOperator<List<E>>() {
            @Override
            public List<E> apply(List<E> list) {
                List<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>();
                for (E e : list)
                    temp.add(op.apply(e));
                return temp;
            }
        };
    }

    // This unary operator turns any Set into a HashSet.
    static <E> UnaryOperator<Set<E>> hashSet(final UnaryOperator<E> op) {
        return new UnaryOperator<Set<E>>() {
            @Override
            public Set<E> apply(Set<E> set) {
                Set<E> temp = new HashSet<E>();
                for (E e : set)
                    temp.add(op.apply(e));
                return temp;
            }
        };
    }

    // This unary operator turns any Map into a HashMap.
    static <K, V> UnaryOperator<Map<K, V>> hashMap(final UnaryOperator<K> op1, final UnaryOperator<V> op2) {
        return new UnaryOperator<Map<K, V>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<K, V> apply(Map<K, V> map) {
                Map<K, V> temp = new HashMap<K, V>();
                for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
                    temp.put(op1.apply(entry.getKey()), op2.apply(entry.getValue()));
                return temp;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // In this example I will first create an unmodifiable collection of unmodifiable collections.
        Map<String, List<Set<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Set<Integer>>>();
        map.put("Example", Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))))));
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        // Now I will make it mutable in one line!
        map = hashMap(Main.<String>identity(), arrayList(hashSet(Main.<Integer>identity()))).apply(map);
    }
}
```